# For 'str.contains()', how to filter base on a list rather than one string

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter the dataframe with pandas's `str.conatins()` function.
However, I want to pass on a list `target` that can later be customized by user, rather than a fixed string, is there a way to do that?

I have tried `df.filter(like=)` , but it would not work for me due to it's complete fit nature.

```
target('food','tasty','avocado','mint')
df1=df[df['text'].str.contains('food')]
```

Comment: `df1=df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(['food','tasty','avocado','mint'])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.isin()` [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
target = set('food','tasty','avocado','mint')
df1=df[df['text'].isin(target)]
```